# Finding the radius of convergence of this power series

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need help finding the radius of convergence of the power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}\right) x^n,$$

for some $a > 0$.

I know the radius must be 1 but I can't formally show it by computing the limit of the quotients of the coefficients.

Basically I want to show

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+a+1}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}} = 1.$$

I have tried expanding the quotient using the binomial formula, but I can't get it to work without using handwavy arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can use that $\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}=\frac a{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint :** Here is a direct way to find the radius of convergence, without the ratio test. One has $$\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n} \left( \sqrt{1+\dfrac{a}{n}} - 1\right) \sim \sqrt{n} \times \dfrac{a}{2n} = \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

so the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}\right) x^n$ has the same radius fo convergence as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{n}} x^n$.

Can you take it from here ?